# MDX: generate hierarchy level within RDL report

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, rdl

Let's say, we have a cube with dimention 'Grocery store', which has 2-level hierarchy:

- Fruits & Vegetables Dep.

  - Fruits
  - Vegetables
  - Tomatoes
  - Cucumbers
- Bakery Dep.
- Milk Dep.

The question is - how can I add hierarchy level within mdx query of RDL-report, so that 'Tomatoes' and 'Cucumbers' members would move to the new 3rd level under native 2nd level 'Vegetables'. I need to do that without any changes to the Cube, all by means of pure mdx only.

When I tried to build a calculated set for the desired 3rd level and use it along with the rest part of initial hierarchy like this:

```
 WITH SET [Level 3] AS 
    case 
    when [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].[Level 2].CURRENTMEMBER = [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Tomatoes] OR
         [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].[Level 2].CURRENTMEMBER = [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Cucumbers]
    then [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].[Level 2].CURRENTMEMBER
    else null end

SELECT {[Measures].[Sales]} ON COLUMNS,

CrossJoin(Hierarchize( {[Grocery store].[Hierarchy].[Level 2]}
                      -{[Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Tomatoes],
                        [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Cucumbers]}),
          [Level 3]) ON ROWS 

FROM [CUBE]
```

I faced an error telling, that crossjoin function cannot take one same dimention 'Grocery store' two times.

Comment: is your aim to cross join the two members Tom & Cuc with the members of Level2 ? If this is what you want to achieve then you could create custom members in a different dimension that are equal to Tom & Cuc and then cross-join these new custom members with Level2 .... but if you want to make a new level in an MDX script then it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new level on the fly isn't possible.

Not pretty but one way of getting around this is to create a couple of new calculated members in some unrelated dimension and then cross join to level two.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Geography].[Tomatoes] AS ([Geography].[All],[Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Tomatoes])
  MEMBER [Geography].[Cucumbers] AS ([Geography].[All],[Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Cucumbers])
  SET [Level 3] AS 
    {
      [Geography].[Tomatoes],
      [Geography].[Cucumbers]
    }    
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
  CrossJoin(
     Hierarchize( 
       {[Grocery store].[Hierarchy].[Level 2]}
       {[Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Tomatoes],
        [Grocery store].[Hierarchy].&[Cucumbers]}
      )
     ,[Level 3]
   ) ON ROWS 
FROM [CUBE]
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea. I tried your code. Tom & Cuc calculated members in unrelated dimension are created successfully, as the calculated set [Level 3] does, but the final crossjoin of this [Level 3] with cube [Level 2] hierarchy returns zero rows. I feel your proposal is really what I was looking for and I am very close to the solution now. I will continue to dig the code and post here the result, if any

Comment: after several attempts to populate empty cells with data - I gave up and left original hieararchy in my report, just made font weight bold for Fruites and Vegetables - in the rdl grid. Still I consider @whytheq gave me the right direction for further attempts

Comment: I've continued studying of calculated members within sets in a related thread "MDX: generate 2 members 'old clients' & 'new cliends' and show sales stats for them" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436277/mdx-generate-2-members-old-clients-new-cliends-and-show-sales-stats-for-t). @whytheq, it would be great if you look at it