# SSRS mdx report: use dimension on columns

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, olap, dimension, rdl

This simple mdx query do work in SSMS:

```
SELECT  
CrossJoin({[Measures].[Qnt]},
          {[Sales_step].CHILDREN}) ON COLUMNS,
[City] ON ROWS  
FROM [SALES_PIPE]
```

But it fails to run within Visual Studio for rdl report. An error accures:

```
The query cannot be prepared: The query must have at least one axis. 
The first axis of the query should not have multiple hierarchies, 
nor should it reference any dimension other than the Measures dimension..
Parameter name: mdx (MDXQueryGenerator)
```

I've found another syntax to retrieve results, but it's cols are hardcoded and script is slow:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Contacts] AS 
       CASE WHEN [Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[contact]               
       THEN [Measures].[Qnt] ELSE null END
MEMBER [Measures].[Clients] AS 
       CASE WHEN [Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[client]               
       THEN [Measures].[Qnt] ELSE null END
MEMBER [Measures].[Funded] AS 
       CASE WHEN [Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[funded]               
       THEN [Measures].[Qnt] ELSE null END

SELECT {[Measures].[Contacts],
        [Measures].[Clients],
        [Measures].[Funded]} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY     
FILTER(crossjoin({[City].CHILDREN},                            
                 {[Sales_step].CHILDREN}),
       [Measures].[Contacts] > 0 OR
       [Measures].[Clients] > 0 OR      
       [Measures].[Funded] > 0) ON ROWS 

FROM [SALES_PIPE]
```

The part, which makes it very slow - is not calculated members, it is crossjoin of City and Sales_step dimensions on rows, which I have to make (othewise, with City dim on rows only, - I get null results on columns). Any suggestions how can I make my mdx faster?

Comment: Out of interest: Did you ever get an answer to this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568720/mdx-generate-hierarchy-level-within-rdl-report

Comment: Cheers 2whytheq! You are right. We should be very carefull when using Filter() and Crossjoin() functions together. It often makes mdx very slow. As you kindly proposed, I've replaced Filter() block with subcube request - and it made code to run much faster. Then I replaced CASE with IIF and it worked out better too. I will post a new code as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give the same results? Is it any quicker?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Contacts] AS 
    Sum
    (
      IIF
      (
        [Sales_step].CurrentMember IS [Sales_step].&[contact],
       ,[Measures].[Qnt]
       ,null
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Clients] AS 
    Sum
    (
      IIF
      (
        [Sales_step].CurrentMember IS [Sales_step].&[client]
       ,[Measures].[Qnt]
       ,null
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Funded] AS 
    Sum
    (
      IIF
      (
        [Sales_step].CurrentMember IS [Sales_step].&[funded]
       ,[Measures].[Qnt]
       ,null
      )
    ) 
  SET [yourMeasures] AS 
    {
      [Measures].[Contacts]
     ,[Measures].[Clients]
     ,[Measures].[Funded]
    } 
  SET [CitySales] AS 
    [City].Children * [Sales_step].Children 
  SET [CitySalesNonEmpty] AS 
    Union
    (
      NonEmpty([CitySales],[Measures].[Contacts])
     ,NonEmpty([CitySales],[Measures].[Clients])
     ,NonEmpty([CitySales],[Measures].[Funded])
    ) 
/*
//>>>>Alternative syntax for above union>>
  SET [CitySalesNonEmpty] AS 
      NonEmpty([CitySales],[Measures].[Contacts])
     +NonEmpty([CitySales],[Measures].[Clients])
     +NonEmpty([CitySales],[Measures].[Funded])
//>>>>
*/
SELECT 
  [yourMeasures] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [CitySalesNonEmpty] ON ROWS
FROM [SALES_PIPE];
```

Comment: I consider your coding technics in this snippet is very interesting and usefull to utilize in mdx scripts on the whole. I strongly appreciate your help, thank you !!!

Comment: @Globe don't be scared to mark it as the answer! Using `IIF` with `NULL` on one of the logic branches means that the measure works in block-mode; this was effectively the answer to your question.

Comment: Man, I do want balls like yours. Marked it as an answer

Comment: @Globe appreciated. Going back to the question: why not just have the measures on Columns, with your cross join on rows. Then in SSRS use a matrix and then select each measure into each row of the matrix ... hence, effectively pivoting the data. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Beautiful code. You are turning into a legend of sorts in MDX tag on SO, eh? ;)

Comment: @whytheq - Suggest you to review your code a bit. You don't really need the SUM function in the member's definition.

Comment: @whytheq - How can I force your mdx to output only [City] on rows? That from calculated set [CitySalesNonEmpty], without [Sales_step]. I tried to use "non empty [CitySalesNonEmpty].[City] on rows" - but an error accures 'there is no [CitySalesNonEmpty] dimension in the cube'

Comment: @Globe hi - hope you are well - should be quite easy just try the `Extract` function: it gives the behaviour of extracting just a specified hierarchy from a set of multi-dimensional tuples. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145980.aspx

Comment: @whytheq - I'v tested this Extract(): it does permit to output desired columns, that's good. Can I also force it to show statistics, which disappears too, if I would not use crossjoin of City and Sales_step dimensions on rows, which I have to make (othewise, with City dim on rows only, - I get null results on columns)? I wrote about it before. Now, I would like to output City on rows only, to make query run lighter and faster with less rows. But I can't avoide statistics loss, let's say for contacts column. Neither without crossjoin, no with crossjoin + following extract. Need your suggestion

Comment: @Globe not 100% sure what the scenario is: maybe a new question would help explain things better?

Comment: @whytheq, I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648124/ssrs-mdx-report-dimenstion-on-columns-outputs-nulls-if-not-selected-on-rows-als

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below query in SSRS.

```
SELECT  [Measures].[Qnt] ON COLUMNS,
NonEmpty
        (
         [Sales_step].CHILDREN 
         * 
         [City], [Measures].[Qnt]
        ) ON ROWS       
FROM [SALES_PIPE]
```

Having said that, I am assuming you are declaring the named set `[City]` above this bit of code.

Comment: This code produces grid with 3 columns: Sales_step, City, Qnt. But I need a format like: City, Contacts, Clients, Funded. It's like Pivot command in t-sql or transpose in Excel

Comment: Hmm. The reason I gave this answer is because you said that your earliest attempt didn't work. It seems you want the second MDX to be optimized.

Comment: I need either of two things: (a) to force short code snippet to run in SSRS or (b) as an alternative - optimize heavy code snippet with calculated members and crossjoin on rows to run fast. In SSMS they give the same 4 cols outcome: City, Contacts, Clients, Funded

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @whytheq's proposal to avoid using slow Filter() func and CASE condition - I post a new optimised code here with subcube request and IIF condition. It runs much faster:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Contacts] AS 
       IIF([Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[contact], [Measures].[Qnt], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[Clients] AS 
       IIF([Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[client], [Measures].[Qnt], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[Funded] AS 
       IIF([Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[funded], [Measures].[Qnt], null)

SELECT {[Measures].[Contacts],
        [Measures].[Clients],
        [Measures].[Funded]} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY     
       crossjoin({[City].CHILDREN},                            
                 {[Sales_step].CHILDREN}) ON ROWS 

FROM ( SELECT ( [Sales_step].MEMBERS ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [SALES_PIPE])
```