# SSRS mdx report: dimenstion on columns outputs nulls if not selected on rows also

Tags: reporting-services, extract, mdx, rdl

(this question continues thread ["SSRS mdx report: use dimension on columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975618/ssrs-mdx-report-use-dimension-on-columns/30979507?noredirect=1#comment51210115_30979507), answered by **@whytheq**)

This correct code was built in the previouse thread:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Contacts] AS 
       IIF([Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[contact], [Measures].[Qnt], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[Clients] AS 
       IIF([Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[client], [Measures].[Qnt], null)
MEMBER [Measures].[Funded] AS 
       IIF([Sales_step].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Sales_step].&[funded], [Measures].[Qnt], null)

SELECT {[Measures].[Contacts],
        [Measures].[Clients],
        [Measures].[Funded]} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY     
       crossjoin({[City].CHILDREN},                            
                 {[Sales_step].CHILDREN}) ON ROWS 

FROM ( SELECT ( [Sales_step].MEMBERS ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [SALES_PIPE])
```

it produces proper result:

[image]

Now I want to reduce quantity of rows to one [City] dimension only to get result like:

[image]

To do that I've tried 2 changes to the code:

(1) remove crossjoin:

```
NON EMPTY     
       crossjoin({[City].CHILDREN},                            
                 {[Sales_step].CHILDREN}) ON ROWS
```

with one [City] dimension only:

```
NON EMPTY [City].CHILDREN ON ROWS
```

(2) leave crossjoin and incapsulate it in Extract() func:

```
       Extract(
       crossjoin({[City].CHILDREN},                            
                 {[Sales_step].CHILDREN}), 
       [City]) ON ROWS
```

but both variants give empty cells:

[image]

How can I get brief results for one [City] dimension on rows only?

Answer (score 0):

If you try switching your measures to tuples what happens?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Contacts] AS 
    (
      [Sales_step].&[contact]
     ,[Measures].[Qnt]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Clients] AS 
    (
      [Sales_step].&[client]
     ,[Measures].[Qnt]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Funded] AS 
    (
      [Sales_step].&[funded]
     ,[Measures].[Qnt]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Contacts]
   ,[Measures].[Clients]
   ,[Measures].[Funded]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [City].Children ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [Sales_step].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
  FROM [SALES_PIPE]
);
```

Comment: It's interesting and I tryed it, but result is the same - nulls. Dear @whytheq, guess more, please

Answer (score 0):

Simply have:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY [City].CHILDREN ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY [Sales_step].CHILDREN ON COLUMNS
FROM [SALES_PIPE]
WHERE ([Measures].[Qnt])
```

Comment: it gives nulls. [Sales_step] is a hierarchy, not a measure. it can not work in such a manner

Comment: It will because there is a measure in `WHERE` clause. It gives `NULL` because there are no values of `Measures.Qnt` for the possible pairs of `city` vs `Sales_Step`

Comment: @Globe What happens when you browse the cube with `City`, `Sales_step` and `Measures.Qnt`?