# MDX: generate 2 members 'old clients' & 'new cliends' and show sales stats for them

Tags: reporting-services, calendar, mdx, olap

First of all, I need to split all clients in 2 categories:

- 'new client' - came in 2015 year
- 'old client' - came in 2000-2014 years

To do this - I push them into unrelated dimension 'Calendar'. And it works fine (while pushing them to original [Client] dimension - would raize error, I've checked it). But then, after these calculated members are raized, I fail to get sales stats for them. Here is my code:

```
WITH     
MEMBER [Calendar].[Year].[new clients] AS ([Calendar].[All], {[Client].[Year come].&[2015-01-01]})
MEMBER [Calendar].[Year].[old clients] AS ([Calendar].[All], {[Client].[Year come].&[2000-01-01]:
                                                              [Client].[Year come].&[2014-01-01]})

SET [Client type] AS {[Calendar].[Year].[new clients], 
                      [Calendar].[Year].[old clients]}

SELECT [Measures].[Sales] ON COLUMNS,   
NON EMPTY [Client type] ON ROWS 

FROM [CUBE]
```

Here is the outcome it gives:

[image]

If I replace calculated set [Client type] with original dimension [Client].[Year come], i.e. change 1 code line from

```
NON EMPTY [Client type] ON ROWS
```

to

```
NON EMPTY [Client].[Year come] ON ROWS
```

then mdx outputs result fine, without errors:

[image]

but I need to push figures from [Measures].[Sales] into two rows: old and new clients. Not for each year clients came to company. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're script is pretty much done - just try adding Aggregate around the tuples:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Calendar].[Year].[new clients] AS 
    Aggregate(([Calendar].[All],[Client].[Year come].&[2015-01-01])) 
  MEMBER [Calendar].[Year].[old clients] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      (
        [Calendar].[All]
       ,{
          [Client].[Year come].&[2000-01-01] : [Client].[Year come].&[2014-01-01]
        }
      )
    ) 
  SET [Client type] AS 
    {
      [Calendar].[Year].[new clients]
     ,[Calendar].[Year].[old clients]
    } 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Sales] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Client type] ON ROWS
FROM [CUBE];
```

Comment: it works! Dear @whytheq, can you also provide some hints to make Aggregate() function work faster. Is there any way to force this slow func. to aggregate calculated members only in defenite measures, for example?

Comment: After several hours of attempts and fails - I'v found a trick to boost productivity. Look my post below

Comment: @globe - brilliant : I'm interested in your code please add

Answer (score 1):

Here is valuable addition to **@whytheq**'s answer. Samples in [MSDN article for Aggregate() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145524(v=sql.105).aspx) use this condition:

```
WHERE [Mearsures].[Your measure]
```

I failed to use WHERE, because I have my measure on columns already. That is why I tried to add Filter() func to rows select:

```
NON EMPTY FILTER([Client type], [Measures].[Sales] > 0) ON ROWS
```

This boosted mdx speed radically and made use of Aggregate() func absolutely comfortable. But after that, when I added a dozen of other measures, - the speed falled down drammatically again! Any codsiderations how to solve this productivity problem?

Comment: further manupulations with code led me to a fast sufficiant combination of 2-3 measures in the Filter() function. Also I found, that there is no problem with big number of mearsures on rows actually. The very problem lies in one of them only. When I switch it off - mdx fires out in 1 second. When I switch it on - it runs till timeout. Now I will dig dipper to find what's wrong with that one measure

Comment: the problem with that extremely slow calculated measure appeared to be in [Unknownmember], which I include to [Calendar].[Year].[new clients]
attribute. If I exclude this [Unknownmember] - that measure goes well too (p.s.: edit to prev. comment: "... measures on cols ... ")

Comment: (upped) good addition. If [Unknownmember] is a calculated member then maybe there is a problem in its calculation: possibly not calculating in a sparse manner? This is sparse `IIF(condition, null, x)` due to one of the branches being null whereas this is not `IIF(condition, "unknown", x)` as it will return results in massive areas of the cube.